# Vue2 + JQuery library - preventing infinite loop, private property in the component needed

Tags: vuejs2

I'm making a component wrapper for jQuery library in Vue2.

In the component I have an input field set as v-model and main vue instance can update it and read it.

Vue2 Component can update it as well.

If Vue2 updated the field, I need to call init function in the library. If change has happened in library, then library sending callback where I'm updating the Vue2 model.

As a result, I have got an infinite loop where Vue2 receiving callback, updating model and receiving another callback...

Callback from the jQuery library is coming asynchronously, and I cannot set a flag for the time of update in Vue2.

I thought I can make a flag saying - something is pushed from Vue2, ignore the jQuery library callback this time. But, I don't know how to make a private property in the Vue2 component.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "private" variables without a function involved. Functions are the only way to introduce a new scope in javascript.